# How to create a restriction(index) in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

There is a need, which is I want to make a restriction. A can define B which means the same A cannot have different value B, but the different A  can have the same B value.
which can be list as fellows:

```
field A | field B

1         2
1         3(not allowed )
2         3(allowed)
4         2(allowed)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/):

> Unique Compound Index
>
> You can also enforce a unique constraint on compound indexes. If you use the unique constraint on a compound index, then MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the combination of the index key values.

So you can do something like:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```